# Is it possible to have nested example-files section for huge projects?

Tags: doxygen

Suppose you have a huge project with hundreds of class and therefore you have more than several example files, but a hundred of example. How to create a nested structure in TREEVIEW for `Examples` section like following?

```
- Modules
- Class
- Files
- Examples
  - Triangle
    - triangle_1.cpp
    - triangle_2.cpp
    - ...
  - Rectangle
    - rectangle_1.cpp
    - ...
  - Circle
    ...
```

The idea is similar as `Grouping`, but I'm not sure if this is possible. I've tried to make several sub-folders under the `EXAMPLE-PATH` and also tried to separately specify each path in `config-file`. But unlike `Files`, in the end they are just merged together under the only `Example` section.

(Doxygen-version: 1.9.1)

Comment: A compromised solution could be: reduce the number of example-file and set some `snippet`. But that is not satisfying

Comment: Interesting thought. Possibly you could accomplish something by means of the doxygen layout file and the possibility there to define usergroup and user sections,though this would require maintenance from your side each time you add an example (file).